# Case when Between Dates

Tags: oracle, case-when

I am trying to flag data on a rolling Date selected and prior 4 months criteria. 
How do I write a case when that says

```
Case when X=1 and Y=2 And between Date- 4months Then '1' 
  When X =2 and Date(Year/month)- 4monthsDate Then '2' 
END ) AS Flag 

GROUP BY MONTHOFDATE
```

Comment: Please post same sample data and desired reult. Also, please post a complete, reduced, piece of code. You may have a look at [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet it to use the ADD_MONTHS function:

```
CASE
  WHEN X = 1 AND
       Y = 2 AND
       SOME_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -4) AND SYSDATE
    THEN '1' 
  WHEN X = 2 AND
       SOME_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -4) AND SYSDATE
    THEN '2' 
END AS FLAG
```

Best of luck.

Comment: To clarify: what Bob means is use ADD_MONTHS on SYSDATE, to define the boundaries of the rolling four-month window. If you have a lot of data and performance matters, you should have an index on "SOME_DATE" and you should NOT use ADD_MONTHS or any other function or date arithmetic on SOME_DATE; do all the arithmetic on the "right-had side" of comparisons. For example, do NOT "group by MONTHOFDATE" as you have in your attempt - assuming you mean to use some extract function to retrieve the month from SOME_DATE. That would prevent the Oracle engine from using the index on SOME_DATE.

Comment: Does the above mean that X =1 the entire all 4 months of the rolling date?